# How to make first radio button selected by default in a list built with a for in loop using twig?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I'm using twig to make a list of radio buttons with Database values. It's something like:

```
{% for usermembershiptype in usermembershiptypes %}
    <div class="ms_type noline">
        <p>{{ usermembershiptype.description}}</p>
        <label class="ms_price ms_odd">${{ usermembershiptype.price }}<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="{{ usermembershiptype.id }}"/></label>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want the first radio button to be selected by default but when using a for in loop, I'm not sure about how to refer to the first radio button.

Any advices? Javascript and Jquery Solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Using jQuery we can do something like this :
$("input:radio").first()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [loop.index](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) and [if condition](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html) like

```
{% for usermembershiptype in usermembershiptypes %}
    <div class="ms_type noline">
        <p>{{ usermembershiptype.description}}</p>
        <label class="ms_price ms_odd">${{ usermembershiptype.price }}<span>/year</span>
            {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="{{ usermembershiptype.id }}" checked/>
            {% else %}
                <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="{{ usermembershiptype.id }}"/>
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: not tested

---

Using `loop.first`

```
{% for usermembershiptype in usermembershiptypes %}
    <div class="ms_type noline">
        <p>{{ usermembershiptype.description}}</p>
        <label class="ms_price ms_odd">${{ usermembershiptype.price }}<span>/year</span>
            {% if loop.first %}
                <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="{{ usermembershiptype.id }}" checked/>
            {% else %}
                <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="{{ usermembershiptype.id }}"/>
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Also [loop.first](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) is a good options in this case

Comment: @Matteo yes.. missed that